# Can I detect nuclear explosions with coherer?

Tags: electromagnetic

The metal particles would cling together or "cohere", reducing the initial high resistance of the device, thereby allowing an electric current to flow through it. they use it as radio receiver in 1890, What I want to know:

- Is it possible to detect electromagnetic field of nuclear explosions with this simple method or I need more advanced technology?!

[image]

Comment: Even if you can, how are you going to test it?

Comment: @MattYoung by detonating a nuclear bomb, obviously /s

Comment: For that I have asked! I don't know how can I test this method! from what I know lighting can active this device too!

Comment: @MattYoung http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65405/watching-nuclear-tests-as-a-foreigner/65409#65409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect the impulse that way, yes.

You would do better to use a diode of some sort, though.

Any society capable of building an A-Bomb is also capable of building a diode and a better detector.
A-Bombs have a fair amount of electronics in them for the detontation mechanism - the shaped charges have to be set off at the correct time in the correct sequence to get an explosion instead of a fizzle (big, messy release of radiation without the Kaboom.)

---

Lightning strikes will also activate this kind of detector, as well as better ones made from diodes.

What you have is practically an untuned AM receiver.  Just run the antenna straight to the detector with no tuning elements (capacitors or inductors.)

There are schematics available on the internet for lightning detectors of various kinds - from simple to fairly sophisticated.  Have a look at some of them.  Most of them include an amplifier of some kind.

[Here's a lightning detector made with a coherer.](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/cscie129/nu_lectures/lecture6/coherers/coherer.html)
[image]

Note that the hammer for the bell is arranged to smack the bell when the coherer is activated, and to smack the coherer on release. The solenoid for the hammer is arranged to break its own current path when activated - it turns itself off automatically.

This is a MUST because an activated coherer won't release by itself - once current start flowing, it will continue to do so.  Smacking it causes the particles to realign and the resistance goes back up again.

Also note that coherers are mechanically delicate.  They are made of a glass envelope with a powder inside.  They are physically whacked every time they are used, and will tend to break eventually.

---

I assume you are thinking in terms of "world building" for a story of some kind.
It might be reasonable for a more primitive society to use coherers to detect A-Bomb explosions caused by a more advanced society.
It would not be reasonable for a society capable of building A-Bombs to use coherers to detect the explosions.

Comment: It's for apocalypse war :) that's right! awesome answer!

Comment: I was under the impression that a gun type nuclear bomb does not require fancy electronics to set it off. While not as effective as the implosion type, it may be preferred by a society that does not have said fancy electronics but has enough knowledge to build a nuclear weapon.

Comment: @Pentium100:  True enough about the gun type.  The question then being whether or not you can operate the processing plant to enrich the U235 without some kind of electronics.  Merely getting the raw materials to make the bomb takes a lot of technology.

Comment: Of course, you could postulate a very young world where the naturally occuring uranium has a high enough U235 content to be used without processing.  But then, how does life arise on such a young world?  Or was it transplanted there?

Comment: @JRE it could be that the society never developed radio theory and would not try to use a diode in that way. I wonder how advanced vacuum tubes one needs to enrich uranium with the most simple method possible.

Comment: I don't think you can quite separate it that cleanly.  The technology to make an A-bomb takes a lot of thigns from a lot of areas of physics and chemistry.  I'm rather of the opinion that if you've gotten to the stage of actually building an A-Bomb from theory, then you've got a lot of things in physics nailed down pretty tight - which includes electromagnetism and its effects.

Comment: But then, what do I know.  I'm just some guy on the internet.